# Javascript: using global variable in the function definition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    State.prototype["button" + i.toString()] = function () {
        console.log("I am a digit button" + i.toString());
        this.setValue(i.toString());
    };
}
```

But it is wrong, because the i variable is common for all the function created.
For example I want the function State.prototype.button0() to work as:

```
console.log("I am a digit button" + "0");
this.setValue("0");
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to a function, so that the value of `i` doesn't change:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    (function(i){
        State.prototype["button" + i.toString()] = function () {
            console.log("I am a digit button" + i.toString());
            this.setValue(i.toString());
        };
    })(i);
}
```